# How to Stop a Live Activity from The Dynamic island

Tags: ios, swift

I'm Having a problem with Ending a Live Activity form the Dynamic island, I tried Using a Button with an Intent but i couldn't get it to Work Duo to Low resouces about the App Inents FrameWork.

```swift
@available(iOS 17.0, *)
struct EndActivity: AppIntent,LiveActivityIntent {
     static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "End Live Activity"
     
     func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
                let content = MyWidgetsAttributes.ContentState()
                 DownloadsView().stopActiviry()
                print("Activity Ended \n")
          
          return .result()
     }
}
```

The stopActiviry() function:

```swift
func stopActiviry(){
          Task {
                let content = MyWidgetsAttributes.ContentState()
                await activity?.end(using: content,dismissalPolicy: .immediate)
                print("Activity Ended \n")
          }
     }
```